# Angular - Dynamically add/remove validators

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have a `FormGroup` defined like below:

```
this.businessFormGroup: this.fb.group({
    'businessType': ['', Validators.required],
    'description': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(200)])],
    'income': ['']
  })
```

Now when `businessType` is `Other` , I want to remove `Validators.required` validator from `description`. And if `businessType` is not `Other`, I want to add back the `Validators.required`.

I am using the below code to dynamically add/remove the `Validators.required`. However, it clears the existing `Validators.maxLength` validator.

```
if(this.businessFormGroup.get('businessType').value !== 'Other'){
    this.businessFormGroup.get('description').validator = <any>Validators.compose([Validators.required]);               
} else {                
    this.businessFormGroup.get('description').clearValidators();               
}

this.businessFormGroup.get('description').updateValueAndValidity();
```

My question is, how can I retain the existing validators when adding/removing the `required` validator.

Comment: the validators are storage like a array , you will need to handle the list of validators applied by yourself

Comment: sadly this is not possible, angular seems to merge the applied validators internally therefore you can only call `clear` and `set` functions

Comment: @Ricardo thats wrong, validators are composed into a single function and thats it. With the current implementation of the API its not possible to check which validators are set for a control

Comment: As of 12.2 (August 2021), you can now use the new methods `addValidators`, `removeValidators`, `hasValidator`, and their async counterparts. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#addvalidators

Answer (score 155, accepted):

If you are using Angular 12.2 or higher, you can use the `AbstractControl` methods `addValidators`, `removeValidators`, and `hasValidator`, [as per the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#addvalidators):

```
if(this.businessFormGroup.get('businessType').value !== 'Other'){
    this.businessFormGroup.get('description').addValidators(Validators.required);               
} else {                
    this.businessFormGroup.get('description').clearValidators();               
}
```

For older versions, Angular forms have a built in function [setValidators()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators) that enables programmatic assignment of Validators. However, this will overwrite your validators.

For your example you can do:

```
if(this.businessFormGroup.get('businessType').value !== 'Other'){
    this.businessFormGroup.controls['description'].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(200)]);              
} else {                
    this.businessFormGroup.controls['description'].setValidators([Validators.maxLength(200)]);               
}
this.businessFormGroup.controls['description'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

It is important to keep in mind that **by using this method you will overwrite your existing validators** so you will need to include all the validators you need/want for the control that you are resetting.

Comment: note that the setValidators will overwrite previously setted validators, meaning that the maxLength will be overwritten and wont be regenerated with this approach

Comment: Thanks @Jota.Toledo. That is an important behavior to be aware of. Updated the answer to include it.

Comment: I think that use a customValidator that take account of bussinesType and description is a "more natural" idea that remove/add validators

Comment: @Eliseo you are right that having a custom validator is better approach but in my case I have validation rules defined in a json file and I am looking for a more generic implementation and solution provided by Narm is probably the way to go.

Comment: For me this only worked after calling  updateValueAndValidity() afterwards, as suggested in the linked docs (using Angular version 8)

Answer (score 52):

This one work for me

```
onAddValidationClick(){
    this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].updateValueAndValidity();
}

onRemoveValidationClick(){
    this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].clearValidators();
    this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Answer (score 26):

If you change the "validator required" more than one time (for example, using a checkbox) you should add this:

```
this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].setErrors(null);
```

So:

```
  onAddValidationClick(){
         this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].setValidators(Validators.required);
        this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].updateValueAndValidity();
      }

onRemoveValidationClick(){
         this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].setErrors(null);
         this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].clearValidators();
        this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].updateValueAndValidity();
      }
```

Comment: It's working with setErrors(null);.    But updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf : true}); it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

The naive approach would be to set the validators of the control whenever the conditional variable changes. But we can actually do better than that by using some indirection + functional programming.

Consider the existence of a `descriptionIsRequired` getter, that acts as a boolan flag.

Ideas:

- Create a custom validator function that takes the `descriptionIsRequired` as argument and depending on it validates a control against required + maxLength or maxLength.
- Bind the custom validator to the description control in such a way, that when the validity of the control is evaluated, the newest value of `descriptionIsRequired` should be considered.

The first point is pretty straight forward to implement:

```
function descriptionValidator(required: boolean): ValidatorFn {
  return (formControl: FormControl): ValidationErrors => {
    if (required) {
      return Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(200)])(formControl);
    } else {
      return Validators.maxLength(200)(formControl);
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that this is a self capsulated function.

The second point is a little bit more tricky, but in the end it looks like this:

```
export class FooComponent {
  constructor(){
    this.form = fb.group({
      description: ['initial name', this.validator()]
    });
  }

  private get descriptionIsRequired(): boolean {
   ...
  }

  private validator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: FormControl): ValidationErrors => descriptionValidator(this.descriptionIsRequired)(c);
  }
}
```

A small explanation of what is happening:

- the `validator` method returns a function
- the function returned by `validator` could be considered a *factory method*: whenever its invoked, returns a new function, more specifically, a new instance of our `descriptionValidator` using the newest `descriptionIsRequired` value.

A live demo in the following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditional-valid)

Comment: +1 It's valid solution but I am looking for a more generic implementation as my validation rules are defined in a json file.

Comment: I wonder what do you mean by generic in this context. The only way I  see for this to be generalized is that you have a collection of validators `V` that always have to be active in a control. Where they come from is irrelevant. Then you have another collection of validators `Vop`, in this case a collection with only required in it, that can and can not be active in a control depending on a boolean condition. Am I right? If no, please further explain what is your concept of "more generic" implementation.

Comment: cheers! this gave me a good idea to do something generic I needed to do

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this helps:

Adding Validators.required to the validatorset of an existing `AbstractControl`:

```
if (c.validator !== null) {
        c.setValidators([c.validator, Validators.required])
  } else {
        c.setValidators([Validators.required])
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone still looking for an answer, you can do it like this ,handle it in ngOnInit() or any place that you like.

```
   const validators = formGroup.validator; /* or control.validator */

   const newValidator = CustomValidator.checkUserNameValidity(); 

   /* Add to existing validator */

   if(validator) {
      formGroup.setValidators([validators, newValidator])
   } else {. /* if no validators added already */
      formGroup.setValidators([newValidator]);
   }
```

Follow the samething for asyncValidator as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the "validator required" more than one time (for example, using a checkbox) you should add this:
Very important field!
this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].setErrors(null);

Answer (score 1):

I have Forms that depending on the context require some values but they can be omitted in others. In my case it wasn't enough to call the 'mainform.updateValueAndValidity()'.I had to explicitly update that field when I was dynamically setting the require validation:

```
formField.setValidators([RxwebValidators.required()]);
formField.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true});
```

The key was {onlySelf: true}

Answer (score 1):

The below code is written for adding required validator based on condition other form control.

Change below code as per scenario.

```
export function addDynamicValidatorToFormControls(sourceControl: AbstractControl, targetControl: AbstractControl, requiredVal: string){
  sourceControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
     value === requiredVal ? targetControl.addValidators(Validators.required) : targetControl.setValidators(null);
     targetControl.updateValueAndValidity();
  });
}

addDynamicValidatorToFormControls(sourceControl, targetControl, 'source control value');
```