# How do I add Validations to dynamically created FormControls?

Tags: angular, forms, formbuilder, form-control, formgroups

I am creating dynamic FormArray and FormGroups. In which I am creating formControl with .addControl(). How Do I add validations for controls, which can be required, phone number, email, etc.

Comment: Paste your code.

Comment: Data can be either array of objects or single object

if (Array.isArray(this.resumeSections[curr].data)) {
        if (!this.form.get(curr)) {
          this.form.addControl(curr, this.fb.array([]));
        }
          const arr = this.form.get(curr) as FormArray;
          this.resumeSections[curr].data.forEach((datum) => arr.push(
              this.fb.group(datum)));
      } else {

        if (!this.form.get(curr)) {
          this.form.addControl(curr, this.fb.group(this.resumeSections[curr].data));
        }

      }

Comment: You can use setValidators to add validator to the control. Please refer to this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075027/angular-dynamically-add-remove-validators

Comment: @MayuriMore, I edited your question to add the code in your comment

Comment: when you create the FormControl, you can add the validator too -this.fb.group allow add not only the value else the validators. If is a formControl, simply this.fb.control(value,validator), if is a formGroup, in Angular 8 is this.fb.group(value,{validator:Validator}), see the docs https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group and see that in case of control the second argument is `ValidatorFn | AbstractControlOptions | ValidatorFn[], asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[]` but in a formgroup the second argument is `AbstractControlOptions| | { [key: string]: any; } = null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setValidators([Validators.required])` and every other validation you might want to add.