# How to disable a validation of the field in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a form with validation in the fields. I want to remove the validation on a specific condition.

I already tried clearValidators(), setErrors(null), setValidators(null), and updateValueAndValidity(), but none of these worked.

Comment: We need to see your code, are you using template forms? Reactive forms? Rolled your own forms?

Comment: I used Reactive Forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - Dynamically add/remove validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075027/angular-dynamically-add-remove-validators)

Answer (score 1):

setValidators(null), must be work. It's posible you need call to updateValueAndValidity() in a setTimeout to remove the errors. If I supouse your formGroup is called `form` and has a formControl called `myControl`

```
this.form.get("myControl").setValidators(null)
setTimeout(()=>{
    this.form.get("myControl").updateValueAndValidity()
})
```

NOTE: If you disabled the control, the form don't take account the validators

```
this.form.get("myControl").disable()
```